# PUT request and Location header with jQuery

Tags: jquery, rest

I am trying to make a PUT request with jQuery to submit a form that's supposed to create a new REST resource on the server, which returns a 201 Created with a Location header pointing to the newly created resource. Here is the coffeescript code that's supposed to handler the request:

```
  createNewGame = (name) ->
     $.ajax({        
        url: "/games",
        type: "PUT",
        data: { game: name },
        dataType: "json",
        success: succ,
        error: err})
```

I can see the request is sent and received with the correct status and Location header set but then nothing happens:

The response:

```
 Server Warp/0.4.5
 Set-Cookie Game=game123; HttpOnly
 Location   http://localhost:5678/resources/html/game.html
 Content-Type   application/json
 Transfer-Encoding  chunked
```

The request:

```
Host    localhost:5678
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language en,en-us;q=0.8,fr;q=0.5,fr-fr;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
Referer http://localhost:5678/resources/html/index.html
Content-Length  12
```

If I use a 302 response, then jQuery follows the response's Location header but then how am I supposed to tell the page to load the page pointed at in the answer? Of course, I could use a different mechanismm (eg. a POST query) and I know my request is not REST compliant as the url for the request should point at a specific resource, yet I would like to understand better the issue as I think PUT is the correct verb here (I can construct on the client siide the URI for the resource to create).

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the user within the success function (via javascript's `window.location.href()`).

More importantly, in this case I think `POST` is more appropriate than `PUT`. `POST` is used to **create** new resources, while `PUT` is used to **create** or **update** named resources.

Since you are not naming the resource directly, you should be using: `POST /games`. Otherwise, you probably want to use something like: `PUT /game/unique-name`.

See also [this SO answer for a good summary of `POST` vs `PUT`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/630475/145754)